# Глагол "проводить" совершенного и несовершенного вида?

Tags: глаголы, спряжение, аспектология

Я думаю,что несовершенного вида. Но форма 1 лица ед.числа в предложении "Я провожу вас"используется в форме будущего времени. Но ведь глаголы НСВ вида образуют форму будущего времени с помощью глагола БЫТЬ.  Можете объяснить,пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Из ответа справочной службы русского языка Грамоты.ру:**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=252697)

> В русском языке есть два омонимичных глагола *проводить*. ***Проводить* 1** – глагол **несовершенного вида** (что делать?), образует видовую пару с
> глаголом совершенного вида ***провести***: *проводить собрание – провести
> собрание, проводить отряд через лес – провести отряд через лес.*
>
> А вот глагол ***проводить* 2** – это глагол **совершенного вида**, он образует видовую пару с глаголом несовершенного вида  ***провожать***:
> *провожать* (что делать?) *девушку до дома – проводить* (что сделать?)
> *девушку до дома, провожать гостей на вокзал – проводить гостей на
> вокзал.*